# Arkeia in SuSE LINUX restore with commandline

Tags: restore, suse

Could anyone here tell my why my arkeia restore command do not work?

```
 arkc -restore -start -D file=si105:/Fastora/Moeller from=si105:/Fastora to=localhost:/home/ws -drvname=LTO
```

I always get the ERROR [200] which means by doing

```
 arkc -usage -debug -error

 MLC_ERROR_EXECUTING_FUNCTION   200
```

I have only one LTO Drive attached on my SCSI and the name is `LTO`

I have never done this before, but now - after 5 years - I need to restore a directory from my tapes.